# How to check whether International Space Station is in the dark

Tags: api

I'm building a website whereby if the international space station is in the dark (in Earth's shadow), it will do A, otherwise it'll do B.

How can I achieve this? The closest I have come is a [Flash file](http://wsn.spaceflight.esa.int/iss/ISStracker2014b.swf), which I've decoded to a 3000+ file that I can't make sense of. I've thought about using an API, which I can call every second, that show this information, but have not been able to find one.

Comment: There are lots of sites out there that offer RSS feeds to provide this data.  You could start with NASA.

Comment: @durbnpoisn LIVE data? I can't find any that are live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [This](http://wheretheiss.at/w/developer):

It is mentioned about the ISS too.

The basic gist is, if you visit this https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544 , you will get the details response in JSON, which you can easily parse and use.

note , that the 25544 is the ID for ISS.

If I am not mistake, there is a 'visibility' field too, which you can just check for light.